# Selecionar todas as classes no CSS

Tags: css

Tenho um ficheiro CSS dedicado a uma página, lá tenho todas as classes definidas. O problema é que quando quero imprimir tenho que diminuir o tamanho da fonte para que fique tudo como deve de ser.
Para isso tentei usar:

```
@media print {
 *{
    font-size: 80%;
 }
}
```

O que só alterou certas partes da página. É possível selecionar todas as **classes** ao em vez de todos os **elementos** ?

A único forma que consegui por isto a funcionar foi por todas as classes dentro do @media print { } e cada uma atribuir o tamanho da fonte 80%...

Apesar de funcionar são ainda um número considerável de classes e gostava de poupar espaço.

Comment: Não sei se é o caso, mas vc poderia usar o seletor `[class]` que pega todos os elementos que tem o atributo `class` (ou seja, todos os elementos que possuem alguma classe, que seria o mesmo que "todas as classes")

Comment: Tentei, mas por alguma razão tanto essa opção como a que referi no post não estão a afetar todas as classes que foram criadas

Comment: Então clique em [edit] e coloque mais detalhes na pergunta: o HTML, quais classes ele não pega, etc. Se o HTML for muito grande, reduza para um [mcve] <- leia este link, tem dicas para montar um exemplo que reproduza o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O .class seletor seleciona elementos com um atributo de classe específico.

Para selecionar elementos com uma classe específica, escreva um ponto (.), Seguido do nome da classe.

Você também pode especificar que apenas elementos HTML específicos devem ser afetados por uma classe. Para fazer isso, comece com o nome do elemento e, em seguida, escreva o caractere ponto (.), Seguido pelo nome da classe.

Você também pode dizer ao CSS a tag do elemento que deseja incrementar o estilo, no meu exemplo estou utilizando um títulos `h1`, você pode usar:

```
h1 {
   font-size: 80%;
}
```

Caso você deseje adicionar mais elementos, pode usar:

```
 h1, h2, h3, p, div {
    font-size: 80%;
 }
```

Seguindo a orientação de @hkotsubo, você pode usar o seletor `[class]` recuperar todos os elementos que possuem o atributo `class`.

```
[class] {
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Uma forma que estava a pensar que pudesse funcionar seria atribuir uma classe num elemento que englobasse todo o código e depois alterar a font-size das classes filhas, mas ainda n testei se funciona.

Comment: @DiogoSIlva, fiz uma alteração na minha resposta, pode ajudar.